# .htaccess to rewrite one folder to http - all others to https

Tags: url-rewriting

Currently I have an http rewrite rule to change all http requests to https. I want to do the reverse on one particular folder (change all requests to http for that folder), but I also want the child folders of that http folder to be rewritten to https.

This is my current .httaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/HTTP_FOLDER/*          #want http on parent
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/HTTP_FOLDER/HTTPS_SUBFOLDER/**    #want https on sub folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]         #all others rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/mysite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is actually working as posted. Something is cached on my machine. I tried it from several other computers and it appears to work.